# Why only 1 <h1> is added though clicked many times

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to hook a handler to a button. I hope that each click will add a new line of `<h1>` beneath the `<p>`. But no matter how many times I click,  there's always **only 1** `<h1>` in total. Why?

```
$("#click_me").click(function () {
    $("p").append($('h1').text('i am new bold2'));
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not creating an new `h1`, instead you are selecting a `h1` element which is already present in the page and then appending it to the `p` element.

You are using `h1` as a selector when you say `$('h1')`(element selector), instead if you want to create a new element you have to say `$('<h1 />')`

```
$("#click_me").click(function () {
    $("p").append($('<h1 />').text('i am new bold2'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N6QV8/)

Another version I uses is

```
$("#click_me").click(function () {
    $("p").append($('<h1 />', {
        text: 'i am new bold2'
    }));
});
```

Comment: These answers are correct, but of course, you shouldn't have an <h1 /> within a <p /> at all.

Comment: @Arun, the another version is using a JS object literal as the < h1 > content, right?

Comment: John McCollum brings up an excellent point... it is best to use tags in their intended intents and structures.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just do $('h1') to create a <H1>  you need to use $('<h1 />')

```
$("#click_me").click(function () { $("p").append($('<h1 />').text('i am new bold2')); });
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('h1')` doesn't create an element, it references any existing `h1` elements (of which there is one).  In order to create one, you need the selector to contain the entire tag structure:

```
$('<h1 />')
```